# Send a friendship request in Skype4Com VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, skype4com

Well I was searching codes for add users in Skype, but the only thing that I have found was that:

```
Imports SKYPE4COMLib

Public Class frmMain

    Public WithEvents oSkype As New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        oSkype.Client.OpenAddContactDialog("username")
    End Sub
End Class
```

But It doesn't send any request.. And **oSkype.Friends.Add(New SKYPE4COMLib.User("username"))** doesn't works....

Help plz!! :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add friends with Skype4COM
You must(And I know it sucks)Send them a request by opening the Contact Dialog.
Sorry man.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
u.BuddyStatus = TBuddyStatus.budPendingAuthorization
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Skype1.Client.OpenAuthorizationDialog "username_here"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Sleep 1000


End Sub
```